# setNavigationBarHidden with animation not working on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I use the following code in my app when user click on a button :

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

The appearance animates normally on iPhone but not on iPad. Do you know why ?

Comment: can you check to see if self.navigationController is not null?

Comment: navigationController is not null. The navigation bar appears correctly, the only problem is that there is no animation as on iPhone.

Comment: Is there any other animation at the same time?

Comment: Not on the navigation controller directly, but on other displayed view yes. Note that on iPhone the same animations are displayed so I don't think this make the difference.

Comment: It can be hard for us to find out the exact wrong point if you provide only this single line....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution here may be to put `self.navigationBar.hidden = NO;` in the `-viewWillAppear:` method of the UIViewController where you dont wish to have the bar perpetually hidden.

EDIT:

i found this, may help you;

```
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
    CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y < 0 ?
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height
    :   rect.origin.y - rect.size.height;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
else 
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:shouldHide animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The bar should appear when user click on a button. So I can't put the code in viewWillAppear

Comment: Your answer is working so I'll give you the reward if nobody can explain why I have to make a different code for iPad. I'd really like to understand what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're invoking this in the context of the Main Thread ?

Answer (score 1):

Do check the other code you have written along with the properties of your view. I use this fragment in my universal apps and it works fine on both the iPhone and iPad. So looks like some other setting (probably autosizing properties??) of your views are causing this.

Comment: Indeed you are right ! I'll try to look what I did to make the animation bugging on iPad and not on iPhone. I don't have a clue right now.

Comment: Probably posting some code might get you answers faster on what might have gone wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me. I try with navigation templete for iphone and then that project upgrade for the ipad for two specific device. and run in ipad. Then navigation bar is hide/show with same animation like iphone app does.

try this. May you get more idea.

Thanks,

MinuMaster

Comment: Yes, it's working for me too when I start with a new project. So it must be something I did on the rest of my code that is working for iPhone but not on iPad...

Comment: Yes, You have review you. May be you find any thing related to this.