# What method will be called when Navigation back button is clicked -IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This questions look repeated, but I din't got proper solution for my problem. In my case, Once I clicked back button I want to hide the navigation bar. For e.g. View1 pushed view2, view2 will have navigation bar,once I clicked back it brings me back to view 1 it should not contain navigation bar I need to hide it. I tried with viewWillDisappear method in view 2 to hide, it worked but if I have more view and I'm pushing each view from view1 if I click back button,navigation bar should hide in view1. So is anyway is there to know in view 1 itself that other view is popped. I tried viewwillappear method in view1 its not called. What can I do here.?

This method got called once I initially load view1, not after popping view2..

```
    - (void) viewWillAppear : (BOOL)animated
{
    [root_obj.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

This is how I am pushing view 2..

```
[root_obj.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:NO];
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: " I tried viewwillappear method in view1 its not called. " are you sure? I don't see why it shouldn't be called.

Comment: @inoob I tried.. Its not called.

Comment: I've couple of similar applications, in which my first screen doesn't have nav bar, rest of the screens have. In that i've always added nav bar hiding in `viewWillAppear` and seems to work just fine. Can you show `viewWillAppear` code if possible?

Comment: Or Way of pushing I done wrong ???

Comment: I think you can just call `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHiden: YES animated:YES];`

Comment: @FerozMohideen, even in that case we need to look at the code, but seems like you can go to the next view so it won't have much issues. But i'm interested in your `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear` code.

Comment: Quasi duplicate of [setNavigationBarHidden with animation not working on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081725/setnavigationbarhidden-with-animation-not-working-on-ipad)

Comment: @FerozMohideen, had a gut feeling you'd be emitting the call on `super`. Try with adding `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` after code for hiding navbar.

Comment: @iNoob Sorry, Where I need to add.. viewWillAppear itself not called.

Comment: @FerozMohideen, try doing an `NSLog` in `viewWillAppear`, as far as i know `viewWillAppear` is always called when a view appears.`-(void) viewWillAppear : (BOOL)animated
{
   [root_obj.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
   NSLog(@"VIEW WILL APPEAR!!");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}`, please give this code a go.

Comment: @INoob I did by placing a break point. Okay I will try once again by NSLog..

Comment: @FerozMohideen, don't forget the `super` call. Hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you hide the `NavigationBar` in `View1's` `ViewDidAppear` method

### Edit

I am not sure what the problem with your code but you can do these kind of things in `ViewWillAppear` or `ViewDidAppear` methods for more information [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and check `ViewWillAppear` or `ViewDidAppear`

Answer (score 1):

i think, u have forgot to call viewWillAppear: method of super class.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear : (BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [root_obj.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```